# vuejs - remount after update background url

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a `vue` component with the binding style:

```
<div id="profile-icon" :style="{'background': 'url('+profile.icon+')'}"></div>
<input name="name" v-model="profile.name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
```

The image will only display if I update the `profile.icon` under `beforeMount` function:

```
props: ['profileprops'],
data: function() {
    return {
        profile: {
            address:'',
            name:'Name',
            description:'Short description',
            address:'address',
            user_id:'',
            background:'/images/admin/bg.png',
            icon:''
        },
    }
},
beforeMount: function() {
    console.log('profileedit mounted.')
    var self = this;
    if(self.profileprops){
        self.profile = self.profileprops;
    };
    if(!self.profile.icon){
        self.profile.icon = '/images/admin/icon-144.png';
    },
mounted: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.$eventHub.$on('ImageSelected', (imagelink) => {///<-- I have another vue component for selecting images to emit event and to catch it here.
        self.profile.icon = imagelink;
        $('#profilemodal').modal('hide');
    });
},
watch: {
    'profile': {
        handler: function(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log("changed")
        },
        deep: true
    },
}
```

I did a few tests:

1. if I select the image, I can see the `console.log` within the `$on` has given the correct data from `profile.icon`. However, the `:style` did not update the background image with the new `profile.icon`. And `watch.profile` did not react at all.
2. If I start to type on `input` with `v-model` bind with `profile.name`, everything update immediately, including the background image in `:style`.

I believe I must have miss something to sync the inside and outside of the `$on`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you create an example showing the problem? Perhaps through a snippet in the question or JS fiddle?

Comment: what do you mean by 'on the fly', also seeing the way you defined style makes me think there may be other improvements that could be made.

Comment: I updated more codes and descriptions. Hopefully this will better explain my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate).

So I just `$forceUpdate()` inside `$on`:

```
self.$eventHub.$on('ImageSelected', (imagelink) => {
        self.profile.icon = imagelink;
        self.$forceUpdate();//<-- this does the magic.
    });
```

then the data will update and re-render.